# mOxie XmlHttpRequest IE8 and IE9 DOM error

Tags: internet-explorer-8, xmlhttprequest

I'm implementing file picking and upload with moxie FileInput and XmlHttpRequest polyfills. I'm only using the HTML5 and HTML4 runtimes.

In IE8 & 9 I get NOT_FOUND_ERROR from the html4 xhr runtime when trying to send the file picked from the FileInput.

simple example of code:
https://gist.github.com/derrickwilliams/7390bd8e33aec336c0f8

The error is throw after calling xhr.send(formData);

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem:
My app uses angular and ui-router. The view, where the FileInput is rendered, get destroyed after moving to the next state where the XHR request is actually made. It seems that is only a problem with html4 runtime.

Solution:
I used the container option to have the FileInput render outside of the element that is destroyed during state transition.